# unspecified error in C#

Tags: c#

i wrote a program that writes data to 2003 access database every 1 minute,
after 20 minutes an unspecified error occurs. Any ideas?

Here's the code

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       try
        {
          OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0;Data Source=C:\\DATA.MDB");
          con.Open();
          new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [DATA] SET Minute = Minute+1", con).ExecuteNonQuery();
          con.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
}
```

Comment: Please describe the "unspecified error"!

Comment: I think nobody will be able to answer your question.  There are no details at all.  Please post here at least the callstack.  Also, take a look at the Event Viewer, It might contain some usefull information which will allow you to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Your unspecified error is even more unspecified because we have no idea what it is because you didn't post it. You can at least post a stack trace or something - without that all we can do is guess, and those types of answers are not much good to you.

Comment: anything else .. did you check the event viewer, there might be something specific in there

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: `OleDb` actually spits out "unspecified error" exceptions. If you run the script again, does it take exactly the same time (20 minutes) again? If so, look in the direction of connection timeouts. If not, have you made sure no other program (including MsAccess itself) is opening the file?

Comment: @Chris U: Maybe it's something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/QhshR.jpg)? I've seen that sort of thing depressingly often from certain pieces of software of unspecified quality.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comments that you've not provided enough information to give us much chance to diagnose the issue.

However, try moving

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(...)
```

Out of the timer1_Tick routine so that you're not constantly re-establishing the connection and see what happens.

We typically acquire connections and release them quickly to take advantage of connection pooling but I'm not sure you'll get connection pooling with Jet. It may be that you're effectively leaking connections.

It's just a guess, but worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

[`OleDbConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is a disposable resource. You must dispose it manually,

**snip:**

either by using `using`:

```
using (var con = new OleDbConnection(...)) {
}
```

or if you want to bind its lifetime to the holding object, make that holding object an `IDisposable` itself (You must dispose the holder manually, [`goto snip;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729277/unspecified-error-in-c/6729714#6729714) )